# rpn calculator function issue?

Tags: c#, rpn

trying to make a rpn calculator in c# not sure why its not working. is there a error in my program or class file?

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IntStack mystack = new IntStack();

            mystack.Push(10);
            System.Console.WriteLine(mystack.Pop());

            mystack.Push(20);
            mystack.Push(30);
            mystack.Push(40);

            System.Console.WriteLine(mystack.Pop());
            System.Console.WriteLine(mystack.Pop());
            System.Console.WriteLine(mystack.Pop());


            System.Console.ReadKey();
        }
     }
```

Comment: Did you get an error when you ran it? What does "not working" mean?

Comment: What's `IntStack`? Do you mean `Stack<int>`?

Answer (score -1):

Try following modifications :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            IntStack mystack = new IntStack();

            mystack.Push(10);
            System.Console.WriteLine(mystack.Pop());

            mystack.Push(20);
            mystack.Push(30);
            mystack.Push(40);

            System.Console.WriteLine(mystack.Pop());
            System.Console.WriteLine(mystack.Pop());
            System.Console.WriteLine(mystack.Pop());


            System.Console.ReadKey();

        }


    }
    public class IntStack
    {
        private List<int> stack = new List<int>();

        public int? Pop()
        {
            if (stack.Count == 0) return null;

            int value = stack[0];
            stack.RemoveAt(0);
            return value;
        }
        public void Push(int value)
        {
            stack.Insert(0, value);
        }

    }

}
```